Incorrect Login Detection in Python Script
I use this code but the response is "Successfully logged in!" even when the credentials are incorrect. I want to enter to my microsoft account. I can not enter to my account and later verify if it was possible. Please help me.
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://outlook.office365.com/mail/"
username = "username"
password = 'password'
http_response = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))
html_content = http_response.text

if http_response.status_code == 200:
    print("Successfully logged in!")
    # Parser the html content
    html_parser = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    # Print the prettified HTML
    print(html_parser.prettify())
else:
    print("Login failed. Status code:", http_response.status_code)

"I am able to log in" according to the code but even with incorrect credentials
